# Removing unnessary classes from project

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, bouncycastle

We developed a project in java using netbeans.In that we use bouncycastle (.java classes not .class).But the problem is we used only very few .java classes in org.bouncycastle for DES and soon..

### Is there any way or tool to remove unused classes in bouncycastle package..Please provide me a solution

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a free tool called [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) that can remove unused classes from your project. It can also obfuscate if you so desire, and strip and compact as well. Well worth checking out.

Comment: Just for the record: other obfuscators should be able to provide the same feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about removing unnecessary class from third party API. But you can use obfuscating for your project. Because obfuscation usually remove the necessary additional data added by the preverifier to the class files. In addition, obfuscators usually load all classes referenced by your MIDlet suite's class files. For more info see this [link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/28989/1954).

And you can refer [Bouncy Castle Lightweight in NetBeans.](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2010/09/03/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-lightweight-cryptographic-api-in-netbeans-for-j2me-midlets-projects/)